# What is the meta name for short description?

Tags: magento2

In product fields auto generation, if i want short description instead of description should i use {{short.description}} instead of {{description}}. Please advise.
[image: Mask for Meta description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes value that are using in Generation field is attribute code.

For Short Description, you need to use `short_description` as attribute code.

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-fields-autogenerated.html